# “几只苹果？” or "多少苹果？"

Tags: measure-word

Tatoeba contains 2 sententes with the same translations:

[几只苹果？](https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/755839)

[多少苹果？](https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/755840)

Is there difference between these sentences? What measure words can be used with 苹果?

Comment: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21509/when-should-i-use-多少-or-几

Comment: 只 is for animals

Comment: Funnily enough - ABC does say that 只 can be a measure word for *apple*. Some examples of usage can also be seen online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common measure words for apple are: 个，颗，粒

A more appropriate sentence would be,

> "几 + measure word + 苹果?"

While for the other case,

> "多少苹果?"

Is totally fine asking just like that, as it is plainly asking how much apples are there. When someone ask the question "多少苹果?", the reply could be using various measure words such as, 箱 (a box), 篮 (a basket) or 一袋 (a bag) etc.

While "几 + measure word + 苹果?" would limits the answer to the certain measure word.

> A: "请问这里有**几箱**苹果?" B: "我们店里还有**十二箱**苹果！你要多少苹果？" A:"那你就给我**十二颗**苹果吧!" B:"什么？就**十二颗**？我还以为你要**几十箱**呢！"

> A:"小姐，你手里拿着**几袋**苹果" B:"啊，我就拿着**两袋**苹果."